# Sample 1 in N elements

Tags: project-reactor

I have a long-running Flux and would like to log 1 in N elements to monitor progress. The following code logs one in N milliseconds.

```
Flux
    .fromStream(
        IntStream
            .range(1, 101)
            .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
    )
    .sample(Duration.ofMillis(2))
    .subscribe(e -> log.debug(e.toString()));
```

Sounds like [sample(Publisher...)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#sample-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-) can be used to achieve logging 1 in N elements by producing a `Mono.Just("")` for the 1 element and `Mono.empty()` for the rest. But the method does not supply the element being sampled. Request ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Flux#index` to get indexed Flux and log each n-th element. This can be cleanly incorporated to your chain using `Flux#transform`.

`log1InN` utility method:

```java
<T> Flux<T> log1InN(Flux<T> source, int n) {
        return source.index()
                .doOnNext(e -> {
                            if (e.getT1() % n == 0) {
                                log.info("Element {}: {}", e.getT1(), e.getT2());
                            }
                        }
                ).map(Tuple2::getT2);
    }
```

And then use it to log for example every tenth element:

```java
Flux.fromStream(
                IntStream
                        .range(1, 101)
                        .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
        )
                .transform(f -> log1InN(f, 10))
                .subscribe();
```